# Issue with Username Having Leading Whitespace After Installing Mamba and Anaconda on Mac M1

Tags: macos, anaconda, whitespace, zshrc

I recently installed Mamba and Anaconda on my MacBook Pro M1 2021, running macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. Post-installation, I've encountered an issue where my username in the terminal is prefixed with a whitespace. This is causing problems with some command-line operations and scripts.

**Problem:**
Specifically, the issue manifests as follows:

- When I open the terminal, my prompt shows a whitespace before my username.
- This was not the case before the installation of Mamba and Anaconda.
- The format of my prompt string (`PS1`) in Zsh is `%n@%m %1~ %#`.
- Expected behavior: `username@MacBook-Pro Directory $`
- Current behavior: `[whitespace]username@MacBook-Pro Directory $`
- All attempts of using sudo commands are failing

**Attempts to Resolve:**

- I checked the `.zshrc` and `.bash_profile` files for any changes that might have been made by the Anaconda installation but didn't find anything out of the ordinary.
- I tried resetting the `PS1` variable to its default but the issue persists.
- Whoami and id are both returning my username with the whitespace added.
- The "dscl . -list /Users" is also returning username with the whitespace added.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone experienced a similar issue after installing Mamba/Anaconda on a Mac?
2. What could be causing this unexpected whitespace in the terminal prompt?
3. Are there any specific configuration files or settings related to Mamba/Anaconda that I should check?
4. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Information:**

- Mac Model: MacBook Pro M1 2021
- macOS Version: Sonoma 14.2.1
- Terminal: Zsh
- Changes made around the time of issue appearance: Installation of Mamba and Anaconda

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance!

Comment: Has your actual username changed, or is it just how it displays in the prompt? Try running `id` and `whoami`, and see if those show a space at the beginning of your name. If it has changed (and I can't see how installing Mamba and Anaconda could've changed it), that would explain why you can't use `sudo` -- you're no longer an administrator. See ["Changing my administrator user's username has removed privileges"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304640) (and see my comment for an update to the procedure).

Comment: Whoami and id are both returning my username with the whitespace added.
And the "dscl . -list /Users" is also returning username with the whitespace added.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to create a new admin account (see the AskDifferent question I linked and the others linked from it), log into that, and from there change your original account's name back to normal (either in System Preferences, or [with `dscl`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452278/how-to-change-system-username-via-terminal)).

Comment: But all those descriptions are relating to single mode in older macOS…. I have mac M1 (2021) and deleting the files did not work.

Comment: Did you try doing it from Recovery mode instead of single-user mode? See [Piersg's answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac/442453#442453). I don't have an M1 Mac to test with, but the way you trigger Reovery is different (see [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/14.0/mac/14.0#mchl5abfbb29)), and I think you need to change the delete command to `rm /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

Comment: I am very confident you are assigning blame to the wrong thing. Installing Anaconda or Mamba would not change your username. You also say "whitespace". Run something like `whoami | od -tx1` to see exactly what unexpected characters have been inserted. Also, you repeatedly stated that there is unexpected whitespace in your prompt. But if your user id was really modified to include leading whitespace then it is expected that will appear in your prompt. In other words, the change to your prompt is secondary and not really relevant.

Comment: The exact hex in the whitespace is 20 And I believe that is a space in ascii.

Comment: Yes, 0x20 is the code for an ASCII space character. I still maintain, @Villsty, that merely installing Anaconda or Mamba would not modify your user ID. You did something else around the time you installed those tools that modified your user ID. You might find a clue in the system logs anchored at */var/log*. Regardless, just follow the directions at https://support.apple.com/en-us/102547 to remove the leading space. Also, check if your home directory now includes the space char since you may also need to change your home dir.

Comment: @KurtisRader I dont have any admin privileges after my username being changed, and thus cannot access the log files either. The name of the directory is not beeing changed.